# Is it possible in Ruby to define a method which name ends with : (colon)?

Tags: ruby, syntax, metaprogramming

Just wondering if it is possible, by some loophole, to define a method name that ends in a colon.  The purpose it to make things look like this:

```
mymethod: arg1,arg2,arg3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is technically possible to define a method with that name, but you can't call it like that because of syntax rules. (The colon is considered a different token.) You would have to do `send('mymethod:', args)`, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to go for an external DSL than trying to do too perverted things with your language.